# Why use relu before maxpooling?

Tags: python, pytorch

In this pytorch neural network tutorial [tutorial link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-neural-networks-tutorial-py)

I'm confuse why we need to use relu before max pooling.
Isn't the pixel values in the image are already positive? 
I don't know why relu `max(0, x)` is needed. 
Can anybody give me some advise on this issue?

```
 class Net(nn.Module):
  ...(init function)

   def forward(self, x):
     x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2)) # Max pooling over a (2, 2) window
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activation function after pooling layer or convolutional layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543428/activation-function-after-pooling-layer-or-convolutional-layer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights of the neural net can be negative thus you can have a negative activation and by using the `relu` function, you're only activating the nodes that serve the purpose.

Comment: 1. It is possible that weight are negatives but output of convolutional layer are positives.

2. There is no difference between the order of max-pooling layer and relu layer.

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: 2. you're right but for 1. that depends on the weights and the input to the layer.